# Is it possible to store different structure message in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka

Is it possible to store different structure message in kafka? e.g. I posted an {id:0, name:myname} message and then convert to {id:0, name:myname, secondname: secondname} and try to store to the topic, so is it successful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka records have no enforced structure. It stores bytes, and therefore can store anything that can be serialized.

Once a message is sent, it is immutable.

If you want to modify any record, you can either

1. Add an interceptor on the producer or consumer
2. Consume, modify, and reproduce the data, such as with Kafka Streams